# Want to delete some custom user data while delete any user in Drupal8

Tags: hooks

Is there any Hook available for user delete in Drupal8.
I have some custom data in a custom table and I want to delete those data while I delete any user in Drupal8. Can anybody help me out of this?

Answer (score 4):

Use `hook_entity_delete().`

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_delete/8.6.x

```
function mymodule_entity_delete(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
  if ($entity->getEntityType() == 'user') {
     ...
  }
}
```